# How to obtain column type from Oracle OCI select query

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I couldn't find any good answer for my problem. I have to write program (in C language) which reads SQL query from config file, execute it and collect returned data. When my application starts there is no information about columns in query result. I should obtain it from database.
There is few lines of my code:

```
OCIStmtPrepare(statementHandler, errhp, statement, (ub4) strlen((char *) statement), (ub4);
OCIStmtExecute(svchp, statementHandler, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0,(const OCISnapshot *) NULL, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
ub4 parmcnt = 0;//columns count
OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *)statementHandler, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid *) &parmcnt, (ub4 *) 0, (ub4)OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT, errhp);\
```

Now I have only columns count. Is there some functions to retrieve columns data types?

Comment: Please go ahead and read this documentation part http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci04sql.htm

Comment: generally you have two options. 1st execute the query twice (once with OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY, then without it). The other option is to prepare Bind/Define placeholders after the query was executed (I think it is called dynamic describe).

Answer (score 2):

There is `OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE`. The way you are using `OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT` to get the column count, you can use `OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE` to get the column type. For example, here is some sample code that I used before to do something similar (note that it would not match yours 100% but you should get the idea) -

```
checkerr(errhp, OCIAttrGet((CONST dvoid *)stmthp, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
                  (void *)&paramcnt, (ub4 *)0,
                  (ub4) OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT, errhp)); 

  fprintf(stdout, "Number of columns in query is %d\n",paramcnt);
  for (i=1; i<=paramcnt; i++)
  {
    checkerr(errhp, OCIParamGet((dvoid *)stmthp, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
                                    (OCIError *)errhp, (dvoid **)&paramhp,
                                    (ub4)i));
    checkerr(errhp, OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)paramhp, 
                        (ub4)OCI_DTYPE_PARAM, (dvoid *)&name,(ub4 *)&namelen, 
                                   (ub4) OCI_ATTR_NAME, errhp));
    checkerr(errhp, OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)paramhp, 
                        (ub4)OCI_DTYPE_PARAM, (dvoid *)&type,(ub4 *)0, 
                                   (ub4) OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE, errhp));
    checkerr(errhp, OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)paramhp, 
                        (ub4)OCI_DTYPE_PARAM, (dvoid *)&size,(ub4 *)0, 
                                   (ub4) OCI_ATTR_DATA_SIZE, errhp));

    fprintf(stdout, "Column %d: name = %.*s, type = %d, size = %d, \n", i, namelen, name, type, size);
}
```